# UCS2 or UTF16 should I convert to UTF?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, character-encoding

The website I'm currently working on collects data from various sources (human entered). The data is being stored in Nvarchar fields in the database. Currently the site specifies that the charset is UCS-2 through a meta tag. Until now the site has required answers in English. Soon though we will be allowing/requiring at least some of the fields to be entered in their native language (i.e. Chinese in this case). Based on some research and other posts on the site it seems that UCS-2 and UTF-16 are pretty much the same thing with some minor technical differences. If it matters this is an asp.net website running on a SQL Server database. So my questions are:

Is there a reason for me to change the meta tag to specify UTF-16?

Will I have any issues with the way characters are displayed if I change the encoding? (I think the current data should display the same since it's most/all English but I'd like to confirm that)

Comment: The encoding that you have in your HTML meta tag should be the encoding that you use for the HTML document. You certainly shouldn't mismatch the two so your choice is very limited.

Comment: Actually, I'm surprised you specified UCS-2 in the first place. Are your HTML bodies that your server sends to the browser actually two-byte-per-character UCS-2?

Comment: I have no idea. I didn't build the original master page. I just know we need to do this update so I checked and noticed that it's UCS-2. If there are no issues I'll just change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UCS-2 is a strict subset of UTF-16 -- it can encode characters in the Basic Multilingual Plane (i.e., from U+0000 til U+FFFF) only. If you need to express characters in the supplementary planes (which includes some relatively rare Chinese characters), they must be encoded using pairs of two 16 bit code units ("surrogates"), and if so your data will not be valid UCS-2 but must be declared as UTF-16.

IF you can easily switch the encoding specification to UTF-16, there should be little reason not to do so immediately, unless your data is being consumed by ancient software that doesn't know what "UTF-16" means.

Comment: Right now it's just a meta tag in the master page. So it would be excessively trivial to change it to UTF-16 if that won't cause any issues with the current data in the database. I have no idea what Chinese characters we will actually be getting but it seems that since I'm expecting them it might be a good idea to change it; correct? It's only used on a website so I would think any modern-ish browser could consume UTF-16.

Comment: Yes, but like @usr I'm wondering whether you're _actually_ serving 16-bit-per-character data from a webserver -- that's somewhat unusual. Are you sure the meta tag you can see is not being overridden by a charset specification in the HTTP response headers?

Comment: It very well might be. When I make this update I'm going to add a Globalization section to the web config and make both specify UTF-16. That should enforce them being the same correct? EDIT: just checked the site headers; it's specifying utf-8 but the meta tag is ucs-2. I'll fix them both to be UTF-16

Comment: Dunno, perhaps. But why do you _want_ to serve data as UCS-2/UTF-16 in the first place? It's more likely to run into problems with off-mainstream browsers than UTF-8, _and_ will waste bandwidth compared to UTF-8 unless your webpages are full of long walls of Chinese text without any markup or scripts in them.

Comment: I guess no reason really. Also it seems I can't do UTF-16. It just made the output a bunch of random Chinese characters and symbols instead of actual HTML. I guess I'll use UTF-8 since that's what it was doing anyway.